# I can't use fingerprint sensor in ubuntu 22.10

Tags: hp, fingerprint-reader

I can't find fingerprint sensors settings in Ubuntu 22.10 installed on my HP HP Pavilion Laptop 15-eh1103AU. I've tried "settings > Users", but there is no fingerprint option there. Do I have to install separately or it is provided by Ubuntu 22.10?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 is now EOL, if this was a new install you should have installed Ubuntu 23.04; if it wasn't a new install I'd recommend not wasting time on the now EOL release & *release-upgrade* asap to a *supported* release and see if it works there, if not resolve the issue there.